# Exporting Data to Excel, (specific sheet, and specific starting cell)

Tags: export, data, excel, spreadsheets

I have this code, which works properly: (I know you do not have the excess to my file mydata.xlsx, but that is not a problem, I believe.

```
data = Import[
   "mydata.xlsx", {"Data", 1,
     Range[73, 100], {7, 8}}];
xmin = Min@data[[All, 1]];
xmax = Max@data[[All, 1]];
ymin = Min@data[[All, 2]];
ymax = Max@data[[All, 2]];
datanew = 
  Table[{(data[[i, 1]] - xmin)/(xmax - xmin), (data[[i, 2]] - 
       ymin)/(ymax - ymin)}, {i, 1, Length[data]}];
modelf = a + b*Exp[c*(x^d + e)^f];
modelkf[k_] := 
  a + b*Exp[c*(datanew[[k, 1]]^d + e)^f] - datanew[[k, 2]];
res = Sum[Abs[modelkf[k]]^4, {k, 2, Length[datanew]}];
fit = NMinimize[res Length[datanew], {a, b, c, d, e, f}, 
   Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"];
modelf0 = modelf /. fit[[2]];
plot1 = ListPlot[datanew, PlotStyle -> Red];
plot2 = Plot[modelf0, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Thin, Blue}, 
   PlotRange -> All];
data
Show[plot1, plot2];
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]
datanewfit = 
 Table[{(data[[i, 1]]), 
    Round[(a + 
         b*Exp[c ((((data[[i, 1]]) - xmin + 0.001)/(xmax - xmin))^d + 
               e)^f])*(ymax - ymin) + ymin]}, {i, 1, 
    Length[data]}] /. fit[[2]]
Show[ListPlot[datanewfit, PlotStyle -> Black]]
```

Now, I need to export `datanewfit` to `mydata.xlsx`, to Sheet3, and start (for example, in this case) from cell J9.

That is the range J9:K36 will be filled with `datanewfit`
I do not know how should I do that.

---

Any help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: @Bill Sorry dear, I tried but could not find the way. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sheets = Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/mydata.xlsx"];
```

Generate data

```
SeedRandom[1234]

datanewfit = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {28, 2}];
```

Replace old data

```
sheets = ReplacePart[sheets, 
   Thread[Flatten[Array[{3, 8 + #1, 9 + #2} &, Dimensions@datanewfit], 1] -> 
     Flatten[datanewfit, 1]]];
```

Until you know it is working properly, export to a new workbook rather than the original.

```
Export["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/mydata2.xlsx", sheets];
```